# Any working Proguard Configuration for Android App with React Native with obfuscation?

Tags: react-native, android-proguard

When I use the `-dontobfuscate` option in my existing android app with a single React Native screen, release build works fine.

(I had to also set react native configurations for pro-guard from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/proguard-rules.pro)

However, I want to obfuscate my existing app and ignore react-native obfuscation only (since it's not supported as per : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7530)

After commenting out `-dontobfuscate`, I got these errors:

```
Warning: com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.NotAnimatedItemAnimator: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchRemoveStarting(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.NotAnimatedItemAnimator
Warning: com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.NotAnimatedItemAnimator: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchRemoveFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.NotAnimatedItemAnimator
...
```

I tried below configurations and NONE of them work. They either throw warnings during proguard phase of `assembleRelease` or once built, throws exception on first launch of react native screen.

1. First Config Try:

   ```
   -keep class com.facebook.react.** { public protected private *; }
   ```
2. Second Config Try:

   ```
   -dontwarn android.support.v7.**

   -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }

   -keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
   ```
3. Third config try:

   ```
   -keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }

   -keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
   ```
4. Fourth config Try:

   ```
   support-v7

   -dontwarn android.support.v7.**

   -keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }

   -keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }

   -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
   ```

Exceptions like:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in /data/app/com.sampleapp-1/base.apk)
                                                     at com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule.<init>(NetInfoModule.java:55)
```

Anyone with working release apk (Existing android app) with react-native, can you please share your proguard configurations?

Comment: The android.support libraries already have proguard rules included in the aar file.

They'll be automatically added to your project when you add the library.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

Comment: Thanks @ajack. Incase, I don't include the proguard entries for Android V7/V4 support library, I get different errors. I have updated the question with the errors I get.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working configuration to make things work with ReactNative 0.27.2 version. (Takes care of native modules).

Most of the samples and the react-native init projects have the react native settings as listed below. 
2 Changes are - 
 1. remove dontobfuscate and 
 2. -keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

```
#-dontobfuscate

# React Native

# Keep our interfaces so they can be used by other ProGuard rules.
# See http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/466/
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
-keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
 @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
 @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
}

-keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
 void set*(***);
 *** get*();
}

-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

# okhttp

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

# okio

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Bg+ Anti Decompiler/Obfuscator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgplus.Anti.JavaDecompiler)
It's can obfuscate your project: effective & easy (UI setting, not command line config).
It supports:

- Hide string value (helpful when you keep some sensitive info in java source, ex: "Hello world" ->ß¤ª )
- Obfuscate with unicode characters (file-names, main-active class, class, functions, variable,... )
- Hide packagename
- Add fakecode to trap the decompiler tools
- Check resource-string (helpful when someone try to edit the resources of your APK)

Comment: Neoco, how does that work with React Native where you are writing Javascript code?

Comment: bschandramohan. This app is only for Java source. There is another version app for Javascript  code.

Comment: @Neoco ..and what is that ?

Comment: The link is broken.