# Release version of React Native Android app getting 'generic network error' when trying to access API over HTTPS

Tags: react-native, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to run my React Native app (version 0.59.1) with an Android Device that is API 16 and does not have google play services. My problem is that when I build my app in release mode, calls to my API over HTTPS give me a "Network Error" with no further details. These calls are made using FETCH.

The API calls over HTTPS work fine when running in debug mode. I have also confirmed that just HTTP works when running in release mode.

I've seen several posts that suggest creating my own TLS/SSL connection factory but it seems that React Native should be already handling this with their OkHttpProvider: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/OkHttpClientProvider.java

I've also included pro-guard rules shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484643/3178433

I've also tried turning off pro-guard and that did not seem to make a difference.

Am I missing something? Is there a missing proguard rule? Is the OkHttpClientProvider provided by react not use like I am thinking it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I added this proguard rule and problem solved:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
    private final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory delegate;
}
```

Comment: where did you add this? I am facing same issue.

Comment: You'll want to add this to your proguard-rules.pro file